# R: writeLines or write, how to prevent line being overwritten

Tags: r, file-io

I'm using writeLines to write into a file, but it appears that it overwrite the previous line. What is the fastest/preferred way to do this?

**Using writeLines**

```
fd <- file("foo.Rmd")
writeLines('first line', fd)
writeLines('second line', fd)
close(fd)

$ cat foo.Rmd 
second line
```

**Using write**

```
fd <- file("foo.Rmd")
write("foo", fd)
write("boo", fd, append=TRUE)
close(fd)

$ cat foo.Rmd
boo
```

Answer (score 8):

As for `file/writeLines`, you forgot the mode of the open operation. It can be `"w"` or `"wt"`.

```
fd <- file("foo.Rmd", open = "wt")
writeLines('first line', fd)
writeLines('second line', fd)
close(fd)

readLines("foo.Rmd")
#[1] "first line"  "second line"
```

As for `write`, argument `file` can be a connection or a character string.

```
write("foo", "foo.Rmd")
write("boo", "foo.Rmd", append=TRUE)
readLines("foo.Rmd")
#[1] "foo" "boo"

unlink("foo.Rmd")
```

**Edit.**

Like user [@lmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4895725/lmo) says in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845010/r-writelines-or-write-how-to-prevent-line-being-overwritten/45845248#comment78648935_45845248),

> Also something cool to note is that you can mix these two functions
>   together if desired. Try

```
fd <- file("foo.Rmd", open = "wt")
writeLines(c("this", "that"), fd)
write("other", fd, append=TRUE)
close(fd)

readLines("foo.Rmd")
#[1] "this"  "that"  "other"

unlink("foo.Rmd")
```

Comment: For `write`, the argument to file *can* be a connection. Also something cool to note is that you can mix these two functions together if desired. Try `fd <- file("foo.Rmd", open = "wt"); writeLines(c("this", "that"),fd); write("other", fd, append=TRUE)` for example.

Comment: @lmo Thanks. I would never have used connections with `write`. So it seems that the problem was also the missing mode argument `open`.

Comment: Just to give some context to this ansewer `w` means open the file for writing, `wt` means open for writing in text mode.

Comment: @par Yes, I know that, it's in section *Modes* of the [connections documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html). And @lmo was right, `write` argument `file` can be a connection.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the two lines into a vector and send that to `writeLines()`:

```
fd <- file("foo.Rmd")
lines <- c('first line','second line')
writeLines(lines,fd)
close(fd)
```

If you want to make it more generic for different size lists, you could just start lines as the first line then concat the other lines in a loop. Suppose you have a list called `data` with `n` lines in it:

```
fd <- file("foo.Rmd")
lines <- data[1]
n=length(data)
for(i in (2:n)){
    lines <- c(lines,data[i])
}
writeLines(lines,fd)
close(fd)
```

Comment: I would like to use writeLines multiple times.